# Exclude external project sub directory

Tags: cmake

I'm creating a project using Cmake and I'm using `ExternalProject` to include a dependency. That dependency has its own `CMakeLists.txt` and inside of that `CMakeLists.txt` it includes two more directories using `add_subdirectory` and those directories are examples and I want to remove them.

For example:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
  foobar
  URL url_goes_here
  PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/vendor/foobar
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
```

Inside of the `CMakeLists.txt` of `foobar` it has `add_subdirectory(example1)` and `add_subdirectory(example1)`.

I want to remove those two examples from being built.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first check if foobar already has a flag to disable the examples. You can use CMAKE_ARGS to set the flag.

Otherwise you can use a PATCH_COMMAND to remove the examples from foobar.

Update 1, How to patch: You can use one of multiple possibilities

- create a patch file and apply it with `patch -p1 < disable_examples.patch`
- run a sed-script remove the add_subdirectory lines `sed -i '/add_subdirectory\(examples\)/d' CMakeListss.txt`. In this case, delete all lines patchting the regular expression `add_subdirectory\(examples\)`.
- run a CMake script with `cmake -P script.cmake` that reads the file line by line and removes the example lines.

Sadly only the last option works cross platform, i.e. on Windows.

Comment: The dependency doesn't have the option to disable the examples. Any example of using this PATCH_COMMAND? I can't find anything similar.